# rich:fileUpload remove Stop button

Tags: file-upload

I am using rich:fileupload to implement upload functionality in application.I don't want to use Stop button provided by rich:fileupload tag.
Is there any way to remove (or  hide) Stop button .
I tried to set stopButtonClass to display: none,  it still shows a small square - probably the border of the surrounding div.

Does anyone know how to completely remove the Stop Button?
Please guide me on

```
<rich:fileUpload  id="upload" fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadBean.listener}" maxFilesQuantity="#{fileUploadBean.uploadsAvailable}" 
                acceptedTypes="txt,ppt,jpg,doc,xls, gif, bmp,pdf"  ontyperejected="alert('Only TXT,PPT,DOC,XLS JPG, GIF,PDF and BMP files are accepted');"
                addControlLabel="Browse" listHeight="50px" listWidth="auto"   onsizerejected="alert('You can only upload upto 10MB files')" autoclear="false"
                immediateUpload="#{fileUploadBean.autoUpload}"  allowFlash="#{fileUploadBean.useFlash}" 
                stopButtonClass="rich-fileupload-ico-stop"  clearAllControlLabel="" clearControlLabel="" stopControlLabel="" 
                cleanButtonClass="rich-fileupload-ico-clear" cleanButtonClassDisabled="rich-fileupload-ico-clear" stopButtonClassDisabled="rich-fileupload-ico-stop">
                <a4j:support event="onuploadcomplete" reRender="uploadInfo" />
                <a4j:support event="onuploadcanceled" reRender="uploadInfo" />
            </rich:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed issue of completely hiding stop button of rich:fileUpload by setting display:none for button border property.
Below is code for css :

```
.rich-fileupload-button-border{ border:none ; }
```